# Parse E-Mail as HTML/EML/PDF from IMAPlib python

Tags: python, html, imap, imaplib

I would like to somehow parse html code from an specific email using IMAPlib.
I started the code by using the basics:

```
email = "email@gmail.com"
pw = "Pw"
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
imap.login(email, pw)
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(None, "SUBJECT", '"Specific Subject"')
```

basically this returns an ID and I cannot figure out on how to get HTMl code from the body of that UID. Would love to get a little support on that one
Cheers

Comment: I don't know how to do that in python, but it looks similar to how it is done in other languages [IMAP4 Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example), so after the `search` you will do a [`fetch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.fetch) for the UID that you get, and you specify what information you want to have.

Comment: Fetch the whole email `imap.fetch(id, “RFC822”)` and then parse it with the facilities in [email.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html), like `email.message_from_bytes(msg, policy=email.policy.default)`

Comment: Thanks for the help sofar, managed to fetch the UID of the selected email...now trying to figure out on how to properly turn it into html

Comment: https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools